# How to format date in fatfree template?

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

Is it possible and how to format date in FatFree framework inside template using it's own function?

```
<repeat group="{{ @rows }}" value="{{ @row }}">
      <tr>
         <td>{{ @row.idbox }}</td>
         <td>{{ @row.code }}</td>
         <td>{{ @row.createon }}</td>//date to format
         <td>{{ @row.senton }}</td>
         <td>{{ @row.price }}</td>
      </tr>
</repeat>
```

Comment: What, if anything, have you already tried?

Comment: i cannot understand..

Comment: try `{{ '{0, date}', @row.createon | format }}` according to https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#format

Comment: tried..
this date 2017-03-10 12:26:28 is formatted like 01/01/1970 what goes wrong

Comment: That's the because the date formatter expects a unix timestamp. Try to convert it before: `{{ '{0, date}', strtotime(@row.createon) | format }}`.

Comment: thx a lot @xfra35

Answer (score 2):

The framework doesn't offer a dedicated filter for date formatting.

### format filter

You can use the [format](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#format) syntax but the syntax is a bit peculiar, as it is primarily meant for localization strings:

#### with localization string:

`index.php`

```php
$f3->PREFIX='dict.';
$f3->LOCALES('dict/');
$tpl=Template::instance();
echo $tpl->render('template.html');
```

`dict/en.ini`

```
order_date = Order date: {0, date}
```

`template.html`

```
<!-- with a UNIX timestamp -->
<td>{{ dict.order_date, @row.createon | format }}</td>

<!-- with a SQL date field -->
<td>{{ dict.order_date, strtotime(@row.createon) | format }}</td>
```

#### without localization string:

`template.html`

```
<!-- with a UNIX timestamp -->
<td>{{ '{0, date}', @row.createon | format }}</td>

<!-- with a SQL date field -->
<td>{{ '{0, date}', strtotime(@row.createon) | format }}</td>
```

### custom filter

Fortunately, the framework gives us the possibility to create [custom filters](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/preview#filter):

`index.php`

```php
$tpl=Template::instance();
$tpl->filter('date','MyFilters::date');
echo $tpl->render('template.html');
```

`myfilters.php`

```php
class MyFilters {

  static function date($time,$format='Y-m-d') {
    if (!is_numeric($time))
      $time=strtotime($time);// convert string dates to unix timestamps
    return date($format,$time);
  }

}
```

`template.html`

```
<!-- default Y-m-d format -->
<td>{{ @row.createon | date }}</td>

<!-- custom format Y/m/d -->
<td>{{ @row.createon, 'Y/m/d' | date }}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the standard php date() function. The previous answer is a really complicated way to get to the same result:

```
{{  date('d M Y',strtotime(@row.createon))  }}
```

The reason you need to use strtotime is because F3's ::template view renders the variables as strings even if they were timestamp/datetime in the database.